# Kendo combobox not show the Text corresponding to value from modal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-combobox

I have a partial view with a combobox. When try to render partial view with modal(contains data from database), it shows only the value field. i want to show the text field of that value field. Help me please.

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m.divCode)
    .DataTextField("Name")
    .DataValueField("ID")                                        
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:160px" })
    .SelectedIndex(0)
    .AutoBind(false)
    .Placeholder("Select Div Code")
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
    .DataSource(source =>
    {
        source.Read(read =>
        {
            read.Action("GetDivision", "AssetTransaction");
        });
    })
)
```

Comment: What does `GetDivision()` return?

Comment: @ Stephen Muecke, modal with text field and value field, combobox works perfectly on selection. my issue is when try to edit form `return Json(divisionViewModel.Select(c => new { ID = c.divisioncode, Name = c.divisionname })
                    .OrderBy(o => o.ID)
                    .ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: What is the issue? Are you getting any error with json statement? Have you observed response?

Comment: simple Man,
    there is no errors. when i try to set combobox from database it shows the value not text, that was my issue,

Answer (score 1):

There is no fault i found with your view code. Its just looks fine to me. I think you are doing same as [this sample](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox/serverfiltering).

I suspect your value assignment to `c.divisioncode, Name = c.divisionname`. Just make sure you are getting and setting `value and text` properly From your db service calls to view model and assigning correctly. For that you can use and see the "quick watch" `while debugging the GetDivision "Action" in AssetTransaction "controller"`.

**Sample Code i found:**

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
          .Name("products")
          .DataTextField("ProductName")
          .DataValueField("ProductID")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:250px" })
          .Filter("contains")
          .AutoBind(false)
          .MinLength(3)
          .DataSource(source => {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetProducts", "Home");
              })
              .ServerFiltering(true);
          })
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue since my model has attribute for code.

I changed

```
AutoBind(false)
```

to

```
AutoBind(true).
```

Now it shows the Text instead of the Value

Answer (score 0):

You can set AutoBind to false (which you've already done), and then use the Text property to define the text that will be displayed:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m.divCode)
.DataTextField("Name")
.DataValueField("ID")                                        
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:160px" })
.SelectedIndex(0)
.AutoBind(false)
.Text(Model.YourTextFieldToDisplay)  // add this and modify to your needs
.Placeholder("Select Div Code")
.Filter(FilterType.Contains)
.DataSource(source =>
{
    source.Read(read =>
    {
        read.Action("GetDivision", "AssetTransaction");
    });
})
```